# ML kit face recognition not working on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

I'm working on an app that does facial recognition. One of the steps include detecting the user smile. For that, I am currently using google's Ml Kit. The application works fine on Android platform but when I run on Ios (Iphone Xr and others) it does not recognize any faces on any image. I have already followed every steps on how to integrate Ios and Firebase and it runs fine.

Here's my code. It's always falling on length == 0, as the image would not contain any faces. The image passed as parameter is coming from the image_picker plugin.

```
Future<Face> verifyFace(File thisImage) async {
  var beforeTime = new DateTime.now();
  final image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(thisImage);
  final faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(
    FaceDetectorOptions(
      mode: FaceDetectorMode.accurate,
      enableClassification: true,
    ),
  );

  var processedImages = await faceDetector.processImage(image);
  print('Processing time: ' +
      DateTime.now().difference(beforeTime).inMilliseconds.toString());

  if (processedImages.length == 0) {
    throw new NoFacesDetectedException();
  } else if (processedImages.length == 1) {
    Face face = processedImages.first;
    if(face.smilingProbability == null){
      throw new LipsNotFoundException();
    }
    else {
      return face;
    }
  } else if (processedImages.length > 1) {
    throw new TooManyFacesDetectedException();
  }
}
```

If someone has any tips or can tell what I am doing wrong I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old issue, but I was having the same problem and turns out I just forgot to add the `pod 'Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel'` in the podfile.

Answer (score 0):

there is configuration in some many places so i will better left you [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymyYUCrJnxU) video (although maybe you already see it) so you can see some code and how Matt Sullivan make that one you are trying to do.

let met know if you already see it and please add maybe an example repo i could work with so see you exact code.

Comment: I already saw that video, it does the same as I am doing on the code posted. As said, it works on Android but not on IOS. About posting code, I cannot do it because of my company's policy, but everything used to detect faces is on the code above

Comment: Have you checked out the iOS QuickStart example for ML Kit Vision APIs (including face detection): https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/mlvision   (Please note that ML Kit does not support face recognition; it only supports face detection.)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, ML Kit face detection does work on iOS but very poorly.
It doesn't even seem worth it to use the SDK.

The docs do say that the face itself must be at least 100x100px. In my testing though the face itself needs to be at least 700px for the SDK to detect the face.

The SDK on Android works super well even on small image sizes (200x200px in total).